# Globally set Qty Uses Decimals magento

Tags: magento

Is there a way to globally set the "QtyUsesDecimals" option in magento? My

I'm setting up a Magento site for a client who sells Fabric and other related materials. There is a minimum of .5 yards for any one Fabric product, After that, it can go to any amount, but the minimum is .5. Currently I'm able to type in .25, .125, etc. and add those to the shopping cart.

I only want this to apply to the Fabric products (there are around 2000 different fabric products) but not to the other types she sells on her site, like Rulers, needles, buttons, etc... I don't want people to be able to purchase .5 buttons.

Thanks

Comment: did you set it for the Default configuration? that will override everything else...

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering the same thing, and I just googled this for you and in exactly 5 seconds.. I got the answer (and comprehended it too, mind you):

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6193/magento-product-quantity-uses-decimals

And to apply this to just fabrics.. it should be something like this:

```
UPDATE `cataloginventory_stock_item` 
SET `is_qty_decimal` = 1 
WHERE `product_id` IN (
   -- INSERT SUBQUERY HERE THAT GETS ALL PRODUCT ID's UNDER THE 'FABRIC' CATEGORY --
   -- IT WOULD START WITH 'SELECT `product_id` FROM ..' you do the rest I believe in you --
);
```

For new/incoming products.. **No**, there isn't a *global* config that controls this, and **no** you can't set it in Default Configuration as it is already a global attribute. ***Unless***, you are willing to invest some time into making an Observer module that sets that attribute for all new products that are created -and- saved (successfully).

Answer (score 0):

There is a database query to solve this issue if the not fabrics products are just a few, or none.

This solution is not update safe and shouldn't be used unless you really understand what you're doing.

```
ALTER TABLE `cataloginventory_stock_item` 
CHANGE COLUMN `is_qty_decimal` `is_qty_decimal` SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '1' COMMENT 'Is Qty Decimal';
```

This will change just the default value of this column from `DEFAULT '0'` to `DEFAULT '1'`. In Magento 1.7.0.2 the other column fields are untouched, so you can check the query to see if your database version corresponds. Then you should check and rerun this query on each database update.

After executing this query you should modify the value back to '0' to the non fabrics products: you can do all at once via query (check Seth Jeremi Malaki's answer) or through the Admin interface (product->stock) one by one (the secure way).

Otherwise, if the fabric products are a lot less (or none), just keep the database at its state and modify only the fabrics via the admin interface.